# can i show multiple information in item with prime ng and angular

Tags: angular, primeng

i Have object city :  with name and code
Can with prime ng show the liste of citye with : Name and Code, or i can show just one information ?

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBY4N.png)

Comment: i find it mybe in this url with : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/listbox

Comment: What do you mean just one information? You only want to show name ? You can refer the documentation - https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect

Comment: thanks @Durgesh Pal, i find it :)